# How to call api get call on spotify for my user c#

Tags: c#, api

Im trying to get a list of liked songs from my Spotify User via API.
I get the Access Token for the calls to make, even when im using a song ID i get the JSON response for that song.

Now the unclear part, the routing to get my user liked songs is

> /me/tracks

with some additional param for the checking like limit etc...
When i make a GET call the responce is 401 not authorised
[image]

even for the normal response routing /me i get this message.

Am i missing one important step?

Here the code for calling the list

```
 public async Task<Songs> Get_Liked_Songs(string auth_token)
    {
        
        using (var result = new HttpClient())
        {
            result.BaseAddress = new Uri(address_for_songs);
            result.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            result.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            result.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {auth_token}");

            var rez_songs = await result.GetAsync($"/v1/me/tracks");

            var songs = await rez_songs.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Songs>(songs);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the same request on something like Postman? According to the docs: "Unauthorized - The request requires user authentication or, if the request included authorization credentials, authorization has been refused for those credentials."
If it does not work on Postman also maybe the credentials are not valid or do not have the necessary scope.

Comment: Hi, i have tried this on Spotify WEB https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user/  -  and its working. Same Auth key minute after the Build fails on my app. Im really confused. Is this because im using "using" in my C# app for getting the auth key ?